# MySQL query enumerate rows depending on another field

Tags: mysql, field, rows, enumerate

I have this structure:

```
table1    table2
id_t1     id_t2
id_t2
```

Now, I need to enumerate the rows within table2 but by the id_t2 in a single query.

Example of the output:

```
ennum  id_t1  id_t2
1      1      1
2      2      1
3      3      1
1      4      2
2      5      2
4      6      1
```

Leading to rows enumerated with exclusive indexes for each id_t2.

I know I have to use variables (like @ennum) and I have been able to enumerate them globally, but I haven't discovered the right way to do this yet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your example does not seem to contain all data necessary to get output. Can you provide more input data for this example? Basically, what is on input and what is expected output

Comment: For the output I posted the required input would simply be:
(id_t1, id_t2):
(1,1), (2,1), (3,1), (4,2), (5,2), (6,1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks to @JW. I think I got it:

For this to work in phpmyadmin:

1. it is necessary to set variables *running1* and *previous1* to 0 before.
2. the nested query has to be ordered by *idt2* as if not it will not update correctly the running index.

Result is:

```
SET @running1:=0;
SET @previous1:=0;
SELECT  g.ennum, 
    g.id_t1,
    g.id_t2
FROM 
    (
        SELECT  t.id_t1,
                t.id_t2,
                @running1:=if(@previous1=concat(t.id_t2),@running1,0) + 1 as ennum  ,
                @previous1:=concat(t.id_t2) 
        FROM TableName t
        ORDER BY id_t2
    ) AS g
ORDER BY id_t2, ennum
```

Answer (score 0):

give this a try,

```
SELECT  g.ennum, 
        g.id_t1,
        g.id_t2
FROM 
    (
        SELECT  t.id_t1,
                t.id_t2,
                @running1:=if(@previous1=concat(t.id_t2),@running1,0) + 1 as ennum  ,
                @previous1:=concat(t.id_t2) 
        FROM TableName t
     )  g
ORDER BY ID_T2, ennum
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc2d5/6)

Comment: Although this works as expected on SQLFiddle, I've run it in phpmyadmin and it outputs enum = 1 for every row...

This is the right direction though.

Comment: I think I came up with a solution thanks to you. I'll be posting it as soon I be able.
Anyway, I can't find the need for the CONCAT you used. Can you explain me what is its purpose?